# How to make character get up on the blocks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make terraria-like game, and I have a problem. So the 2D world is generated of square blocks. I have to press space and jump over all blocks when I move, but how can I make my character automatically get on one-length block, when I approach to it? I tried to make these blocks not completely square, but with slanted corners, but my speed became much less when I climb on it. What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understod well, what you want is the following: if the player goes straightforward on a single block, he will automatically goes above it, forming a "ladder" system.

I would do the following: look at the image bellow. The green box is the player's collider, and both red lines are raycast.

If bottom raycast return true, meaning that there is one block at his foot, and top raycast return false, meaning there is no block in front of his head, player's Y goes up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a box collider (as trigger) large enough to cover all sides of the box **but not the top**. You can do that by setting the "Size" property of the box collider inside of the Unity Editor (Inspector)

Then in a script you do following

```
public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Climber climber;

    private float height;

    private void Awake()
    {
      this.height = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>.mesh.bounds.size.y;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
       climber.Climb(this.height);
    }
}
```

Then in the climb method you define climbHeight and add climbHeight to the y position of the player (move on the Y value)

```
public class Climber : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public void Climb(float climbHeight)
    { 
        this.transform.position.y += climbHeight
    }
}
```

If you want the movement to be smooth consider using Vector3.MovePosition()